# performSelector with UIControlState

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

In a piece of code where I dynamically want to fire a method on an UIButton, I want to execute the methods where a UIControlState is supplied.

For example, the code I have now is:

```
private func setValue(value: AnyObject, forKey: String, forState: UIControlState) {

    let methodName = "set" + forKey.capitalizedString + ":forState:"
    let sel = Selector(methodName)

    if self.respondsToSelector(sel) {
        self.performSelector(sel, withObject: value, withObject: forState.rawValue)
    }
}
```

In this example, the `forKey` contains `Title` and the `forState` contains `UIControlState.Normal`. The `value` is just a simple string, but is defined as an `AnyObject`. It accepts an `AnyObject`, because there are also methods that need an UIImage, etc.

`self` in this example is an `UIButton`.

The `UIButton` **does** respond to the `Selector` I created  (which is defined as `setTitle:forState:`), and it fires the `performSelector` method without any warnings, but still the title of this UIButton isn't updated.

The problem is probably either in the conversion of the `value` object form `AnyObject` to `String` or in the conversion of the `forState` object, but I am not sure how I could fix this in a generic way.

Is this the correct way to do this from Swift 2, or does someone spot a simple mistake in my theory?

Comment: Private selector should be defined with `@objc private`

Comment: @NataMio, uhm, why? I am using Swift which works completely fine using the private keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after a bit of fooling around. I noticed the `methodForSelector` method and found out, that using an IMP is the solution for my problem.

```
private func setValue(value: AnyObject, forKey key: String, forState state: UIControlState) {

    let methodName = "set" + key.capitalizedString + ":forState:"
    let sel = Selector(methodName)

    if self.respondsToSelector(sel) {
        typealias setValueForControlStateIMP = @convention(c) (UIView, Selector, AnyObject, UIControlState) -> Void

        let methodSignature = self.methodForSelector(sel)

        let callback = unsafeBitCast(methodSignature, setValueForControlStateIMP.self)
        callback(self, sel, value, state)
    }

}
```